# Python ctypes set c_char_p underlying value

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a pointer to a struct. Inside that struct, one of the fields is a `POINTER(c_char)`. I am trying to set the underlying value, so that the change is reflected in any other application with a pointer to the same address.

```
class foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("bar", POINTER(c_char)),
                 ("bazaz" c_int),
                 ...morefields]

z = .... # z is a pointer to a foo

# legal but doesn't do what I expect, this seems to set the pointer itself, not the underlying contents
z.contents.bar = b"asdfasdf"
```

This shows "only on the python side". However, a C process that is looking at `bar` does not get the reflected change.

How can I "manage" `bar` so that I can set it, and that change is reflected in any other application with a pointer to the same address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments, you have a function that returns a `POINTER(foo)` instance.  Here's a working example of reading the return value and changing it.  If your code is still not working, create a similar example reproducing the issue:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct foo
{
    char* bar;
};

__declspec(dllexport) struct foo* func()
{
    /* This leaks memory, but is just an example... */
    struct foo* f = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    f->bar = malloc(20);
    strcpy(f->bar,"abcdefghijklmnop");
    return f;
}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *

class foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = ('bar',c_char_p),

dll = CDLL('test')
dll.func.argtypes = ()
dll.func.restype = POINTER(foo)

f = dll.func()
print(f.contents.bar)
f.contents.bar = b'abcd'
print(f.contents.bar)
```

Output:

```
b'abcdefghijklmnop'
b'abcd'
```

Comment: z is .a pointer to a foo that is returned by another C function (`z = f()` and `f`'s `restype` is `POINTER(foo)`. So Z is a `POINTER(foo)` but I don't explicitly have that line anywhere. Accessing `z` other methods that are not pointers seems to work fine.

Comment: the underlying C function doesn't need to write to `bar`, but it's essentially a shared buffer, and I need to be able to set it from the python side.

Comment: if `z` type is `POINTER(foo)` then `z.contents.bar = b'abcd'` would work.  Update your question with the results of `print(type(z))` and `print(type(z.contents.bar))`.

Comment: I'll update my answer with a working demo from your description.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can reproduce your code in python, however, this bar field is read by a c process (it is a shared memory buffer), and on the C side, the buffer does not hold the updated value that was set in python. Specifically this seems to  set f.contents.bar to point to the string b'abcd', rather than copy the string 'abcd' into the buffer pointed to by  f.contents.bar. Maybe I need `memmove` here

Comment: @Tommy Yes, it is changing the pointer.  You would need `ctypes.memmove` to maintain the same buffer.  Hopefully you know the size of the buffer as well. and you'll need `POINTER(c_char)` as the type instead of `c_char_p`.  This is really a case of needing a [mcve] in your question that reproduces the exact behavior.

Comment: I have modifed my question now that we have narrowed in. Can you please update your answer with memmove? I changed my code to `POINTER(char_c)` as mentioned.

Comment: EDIT: I was able to get memmove working! Thanks for your help I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `create_string_buffer` as described in the docs:

> You should be careful, however, not to pass them to functions expecting pointers to mutable memory. If you need mutable memory blocks, ctypes has a create_string_buffer() function which creates these in various ways.

So in your case, you'd want to do something like:

`z.contents.bar = create_string_buffer(b"My string", 10)`

This points `bar` to the new buffer and you should then be able change the contents via `.value`.
For Unicode (`c_wchar`), use `create_unicode_buffer`.

Comment: z itself is a pointer to a larger structure. How do I do this with just bar? I've edited my question to make it more clear that bar is not the only field. You're setting z wrong

Comment: @Tommy I've updated my answer. Could you share a small, standalone reproducible example if you're still having issue?

Comment: This suggestion blows up with `TypeError: incompatible types, c_char_Array_10 instance instead of c_char_p instance`. It looks like `create_string_buffer` is not returning the exact type of `c_char_p`. I don't have a small reproducible example because I don't have the C experience

Comment: If you run `print(type(create_string_buffer(b"My string", 10)))` it shows `<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_10'>`

Comment: it looks like other people have asked about this: https://ctypes-users.narkive.com/620LJv10/why-doesn-t-c-char-array-get-coerced-on-assignment-to-a-pointer